# How to debug an error in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Minified my code in reactjs using webpack but getting this error, pull down an older branch with no changes that were working before. still getting the same error so I thinking maybe something has changed with reactjs or webpack. Can any suggest how I debug to find the error.

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(..., .0.0.0.0.0): Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a <tbody> when using tables, nesting tags like <form>, <p>, or <a>, or using non-SVG elements in an <svg> parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID ``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely to be due to a browser upgrade, rather than React.

In some cases the browser will automatically 'fix' problems with your HTML, as mentioned in the warning from React.

If you create a React component that uses a table like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then some browsers will try to help you out by adding the more semantically correct `<tbody>` tag.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Similar behaviour can occur if you nest tags that shouldn't be nested recursively (`<a>`, `<p>`, `<form>`), or use SVG tags (`<g>`, `<rect>`, `<path>`) outside of an `<svg>` parent.

If something else mutates the DOM whilst React is trying to manage it, then it's difficult to diff the virtual DOM against it, which is why React warns you that something bad happened.

Your browser probably updated to fix another case of this behaviour that it hasn't always covered.

If the branch definitely used to work, then you can try it in an older version of your browser (or whichever browser you used at the time) to confirm that this is the issue.

Open up the element inspector, grab a dump of the HTML then use `react-dom/server` to render the application as a string, then diff the two to see what shows up as inconsistent.

Comment: Yes, will try the older browser issue because it was working up to a month ago and there was no extra code added since then.

Comment: Actually the answer was that in the react app I used a form tag and in the root html template there was a form tag defined and the react app in wrapped around the form as well which I did not know about - hence when minified and deployed to site the error appeared.

Answer (score 0):

You can use React Developer Tools for Chrome to inspect the DOM as generated by React.

I would also test the unminified version. If the unminified version does not work you will then get much saner line numbers allowing you to more precisely isolate the error than 'somewhere in my application'. If the unminified version works then you have now isolated your problem :)

If you believe this is due to a change in React then test with older versions of React (if possible).

EDIT: I should the error is basically saying someone somewhere is modifying the DOM in a way that React does not expect. Have you added any other libraries? Are you mounting a component on the body element? Does your HTML have any of the issues mentioned?

Comment: No new libraries, the problem just not getting erroring when working locally it's only when it minified with webpack

Comment: If everything else is held constant and the problem only occurs when the js is minified that would seem to identify the problem. Could you try other minification software (uglify, minify..) and confirm whether or not the problem occurs?

If it does not this seems like a bug in webpack.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue **only** occurs in the production environment, the best way I've found to isolate the problem in the most effective way was to build/minify on my local machine and comment/uncomment pieces of logic to isolate the root cause :

```
$ yarn global add serve
$ yarn build
$ serve -s build
```